# Asp.net Load Balancing Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, load-balancing

I am getting a null reference error on a asp.net application when it is on two Azure load balanced servers. When I turn off one the error goes away. When looking at the call stack there is not a real reason why a null reference has been thrown. I have even setup a remote debugging session on both servers and there is not a logical reason of why I am getting a null reference error. My gut says it works fine on one server but not when there is two so it must be a load balancing issue and I need to change my application setup to include load balancing. Is this a normal indication that something needs to change as far as application setup ? If so what needs to change? If not what other diagnostics can I run to get my application working on a cluster ?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at POS.Domain.Manager.GetCommodityList(Int32 locationID, DateTime delDate, Int32 ogID, VMUserProfile profile) in c:\Workspace\Ordering Portals\DanielBranch\POS.Domain\BLL\Manager.cs:line 1123
   at POS.UI.Controllers.OrderingController.GetCommodityList(Int32 locationID, String delDate, VMUserProfile userprofile) in c:\Workspace\Ordering Portals\DanielBranch\POS.UI\Controllers\OrderingController.cs:line 733
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

[image: Manager.cs]

Comment: _"When looking at the call stack there is not a real reason why a null reference has been thrown"_ - perhaps include it in the question though?

Comment: added stacktrace and screenshot of where the stacktrace points to in code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your site is stateful, meaning that you are storing information on one server, so that if a user is sent to another server, that information will not be there. For instance, if you are using in-process Sessions, they will only exist on that one server.

Fortunately, there is a feature in Azure App Services that allows the user to be sent back to the same server each time.

Simply, turn on **ARR Affinity** setting under **Application settings**. This will ensure that the user is sent back to the same server on each request.

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/03/setting-application-request-routing-arr-affinity-for-your-azure-app-service/)

[image]

Comment: What if this is running on a virtual machine in Azure ?

Comment: How are you load balancing? App Gateway, Load Balancer, Traffic Manager?

Comment: Its a VM that is using the Azure Load Balancer